# How to set 'left' with half width pixel

Tags: css

I want to set a dom style 'left' with half width pixel like

```css
.div1{
  position:absolute;
  width:1000px;
  left:calc(50% - 500px);
  height:...;
}

.div2{
  position:absolute;
  width:2000px;
  left:calc(50% - 1000px);
  height:...;
}
```

Because of my code, `margin:0 auto` is not suitable for me.
Also `JavaScript` is not my preferred solution. I've been searching for days with Google. But no ideas for me. Here's the code what I expected.

```css
DIV{
  position:absolute;
  width:1000px;
  left:calc(50% - -WIDTH-);  // it's not right code
  height:...;
}
```

Is it possible to do it?

**I don't want to do it with javascript,scss,...etc.**
thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question would be a lot less confusing and you'll be much more likely to get a solution if titled correctly. I think what you really want is to center align a block element.

Comment: i want to move an element,but when i use margin to fix it.the element will fly.so that,i'll computed many info.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **TRANSFORM** property

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    width:1000px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%) !important;  /* for webkit browsers*/
    height:...;
}
```